# Store module is working only the control panel logged in members

Tags: expresso-store

I am new to the Store module. Store module is working only the **Control Panel** logged in members. If I'm not logged into the Control Panel, Side bar Cart is showing that: "Your cart is empty". When I click on Add to Cart it's not working either. It is working only when CP is logged in.

How can I solve this? any Configuration settings please.

I am using ExpressionEngine 2.6.1
and Store module is: 1.6.4

Comment: Please tell us: what version of EE you are using; what other plugins/extensions (and versions) you are using. If possible, attach screenshots of the error message(s).

Comment: There are no configuration settings which would cause this. As Leigh said, it would be helpful to know which versions of EE and Store you are running.

Answer (score 1):

There are no settings which would cause this to happen or known bugs.

It's likely to be caused by either caching on your front end, or a misconfiguration of your server. I suggest you start by disabling all caches, and also try different browsers etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but one thing to note is that you have installed the cookie consent module and the user hasn't already given permission the cart tag creates an order in the CP but leaves the cart empty on the front-end.