# My cart is empty if I logged out from control pannel

Tags: expresso-store

I am using ExpressionEngine 2.6.1
and     Store 1.6.4

But I am unable to add the "Items" to the cart, when I logged out from Control Pannel(it is showing that "Your cart is  Empty").
But If I logged into the Control Pannel then it is working.

Please help us.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a cross post Ramesh? http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13793/store-module-is-working-only-the-control-panel-logged-in-members?rq=1

Comment: Please don't create multiple questions for the same problem - it only makes it harder for people to help you. You can easily edit the original question to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

In the Store settings is the following item:

> Empty cart on member logout

So when you logout, your cart will be cleared (be that the Control Panel or frontend). When you log back in, the cart will be remembered.